# how does object scope of imported stuff work?

Tags: python, scope, twisted, python-import

--edited after fortan's answer----

from here https://github.com/jdavisp3/twisted-intro/blob/master/twisted-client-3/get-poetry.py

reactor is imported in the

```
def get_poetry(host, port, callback):
  ...
  from twisted.internet import reactor
```

as well  as in the main function.

And stopped in

```
def poetry_main():
  ...
  def got_poem(poem):
        poems.append(poem)
        if len(poems) == len(addresses):
            reactor.stop()
```

**So do both reactors point to the same reactor?
How do multiple imports of the same thing work?**

Also Why not just then define

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
```

at the top of the programs, instead of inside a function just before using it?

Answer (score 2):

The reason `twisted.internet.reactor` is sometimes not imported at the module level is that the *first* time it is imported, if a particular reactor implementation has not already been explicitly selected, a default selection will be made.  Once the implementation is selected, it cannot be changed.

If modules import `twisted.internet.reactor` at the top-level, then as soon as they are imported, the reactor is imported.  This makes it somewhat harder to select a different reactor implementation, since you must do so before you import any module that imports `twisted.internet.reactor` at the top level.

So, one convention is to only import `twisted.internet.reactor` inside functions that need to use it.  This means the import won't happen until the function is called, which is usually late enough that the implementation has already been selected.

Another convention (preferred by some people including myself) is to define APIs that accept the reactor as an argument.  This way you don't import the reactor at all, it is passed in to you along with whatever other inputs your function needs.

One big advantage of this approach is that it makes the code more easily unit testable.

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely, there's another `from twisted.internet import reactor` in `poetry_main` function. The scope for imports is lexical, as with variables and functions.

About the reason to do that, I can think of not polluting the module's global namespace.

Python keeps an internal dictionary of imported modules, so no matter how many times a module is `import`ed; it will be only loaded once and its internal state will be shared among all references.

This is important to allow cyclic module dependencies, that otherwise would end in infinite recursion.

Comment: Thanks but ...I didnt really understand the last para

Comment: Say you have module `a` that imports module `b` and module `b` also imports `a`. If the import mechanism was greedy, it would never end, but as the module loader keeps a reference to the modules as soon as they start being loaded, in module `b` import of `a` the module is handed without having to load it again (which would cause to load `b` again, then `a` again, and so on).